# Unable to send x-functions-key header to azure function app after MSAL authentication in an Angular app

Tags: angular, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

We have an Angular app authenticated by MSAL library per the following configuration in app.modules.ts:

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
}

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]);
  //Note: to add more URLs to protect, please follow the pattern below:
  protectedResourceMap.set(`${environment.endPoints.WebApiUrl}/*`, ["https://MASKED.onmicrosoft.com/MASKED/Backend.Read", "https://MASKED.onmicrosoft.com/MASKED/Backend.Write"]);
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap,
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['https://MASKED.onmicrosoft.com/MASKED/Backend.Read']
    },
    loginFailedRoute: "./login-failed"
  };
}
```

The following code exists in app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;

    /**
     * You can subscribe to MSAL events as shown below. For more info,
     * visit: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/events.md
     */
    this.authService.instance.addEventCallback((message: EventMessage) => {
      if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
        this.signInService.signIn();
      } else if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
        this.signOutService.signOut();
      } else if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE) {
          this.logger.log(LogLevel.Error, 'Login failed.');
          if (message.error instanceof AuthError) {
            this.logger.log(LogLevel.Error, 'Authentication error.');
          }
      }
    });
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
    .pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.setLoginDisplay();
    });
  }
```

We are able to get the Authentication token and send it to our HTTP-Triggered function app (aka Web API) successfully. We also need to incorporate the `x-functions-key` in all headers to be sent to the Web API but we failed to find a way in MSAL library to include `x-functions-key` in the headers.

We reviewed posts on GitHub and Stackoverflow by failed to find a solution. We are expecting the MSAL library to provide us a way to send any headers we want to the backend but we failed to find a way. Also, that will be great if we could eliminate some headers it is sending by default e.g. `sec-ch-ua`, `sec-ch-us-platform`, etc. to have a simpler reverse proxy setup in our docker configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. We need to add a separate http request interceptor to be able to add `x-functions-key` header.